# Instagram Graph API when run through postman giving error : Invalid protocol: "https:

Tags: facebook-graph-api, postman, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am new to Graph API as well as facebook developer account, new to postman.
I generated access token as well as linked my Instagram to my test app, also given required permissions.
After this, I copied my page Id and access token in the URL on postman but it's giving me error.

URL looks like this :
"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

(Removed page Id and access token of course)

Found nothing on google as well.
What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! There was " at the start of the URL!
Once I removed the ", it worked as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue! There was no spaces at the start of the URL! Once I tried to hit backspace start of the URL!  it worked as expected.

Comment: This is copied from the accepted answer.